# Cannot draw a circle by python arcade?

Tags: python, opengl, glsl, shader, arcade

I am trying to draw a simple circle by python arcade.But there are some error like this..

> ```
> arcade.draw_circle_filled(x, y, radius, arcade.color.YELLOW)
>   File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\arcade\draw_commands.py", line 240, in draw_circle_filled
>     draw_ellipse_filled(center_x, center_y, width, height, color, num_segments=num_segments)
>   File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\arcade\draw_commands.py", line 307, in draw_ellipse_filled
>     _generic_draw_line_strip(point_list, color, gl.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN)
>   File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\arcade\draw_commands.py", line 410, in _generic_draw_line_strip
>     program = shader.program(
>   File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\arcade\shader.py", line 220, in program
>     return Program(
>   File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\arcade\shader.py", line 110, in __init__
>     shader = compile_shader(shader_code, shader_type)
>   File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\arcade\shader.py", line 252, in compile_shader
>     raise ShaderException(
> arcade.shader.ShaderException: Shader compile failure (0): ERROR: 0:2: '' :  Version number not supported by OGL driver
> ERROR: 0:4: 'in' :  supported in GLSL 1.30 or later 
> ERROR: 0:5: 'in' :  supported in GLSL 1.30 or later 
> ERROR: 0:6: 'out' :  supported in GLSL 1.30 or later
> ```

Comment: Please show the shader code. It seems that the GLSL version is not supported by the hardware.

Comment: I would guess your gpu doesn't support opengl 3.3

Answer (score 1):

It would be a lot easier to answer if you gave your code. So basically I will give an example of exactly what the program for simply drawing a circle would look.
By the way, this website: https://opensource.com/article/18/4/easy-2d-game-creation-python-and-arcade has been so useful for developing arcade games using python arcade.

It may be that you haven't yet opened an arcade window. Don't run arcade commands from the shell.

```
import arcade
#initialize
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600 #replace with wanted screen height
SCREEN_WIDTH = 600 #REPLACE ALSO
arcade.open_window(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "Drawing a Circle")
arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.WHITE)

# Start the render process. This must be done before any drawing commands.
arcade.start_render()

# Draw the circle
x = 300
y = 300
radius = 200
arcade.draw_circle_filled(x, y, radius, arcade.color.YELLOW)
```